# Authenticating User via Ajax: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in ajax method, but False elsewhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using Facebook to preautheticate users, so when they visit a page, an ajax function is called to login the user, and the server will also check to see if the user is already authenticated to the site.  These users have entries in the user database on the server.

The server side code is below, which is called by ajax.  After that, is a second method I use to get more information on the user that is stored in the database.

When I call User.Identity.IsAuthticaed in the second method, in the same Controller, the User object is still null.  The User object contains all the information in FBReg below.

**Edit:**
After further troubleshooting I found that the ActionResult that calls getUserInfo() has the User object populated.  So I'm not sure why getUserInfo() has a null User.  I guess I can just pass the object then, but I'm still just curious why this happens.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public String FBReg(FBInfo userinfo)
    {   
        ..
        ..
        ..

     if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             if (Membership.ValidateUser(userinfo.id, "FBPassword"))
             {
                 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userinfo.id, true);
                 var result = (from u in db.users where (u.username == userinfo.id) select u).FirstOrDefault();
                 result.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
             }
         }
        ..
        ..
        ..
        return "";
  }





public UserRepository getUserInfo()
{
    bool isauth = false;
    try
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  // User is always null even after FBReg has User as Authnticated with all the correct information
        {
            isauth = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
    catch { }

        // get user info from database to display on page
        ..
        ..
        ..



    return userInfo;
}
```